# Outlook VBA code creating 1 email for 2 commands

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to add 2 things into my outlook message to automate the recipients, subject and attaching in a file. However, when I run my code it opens up 2 new emails for each variable display. I was unable to find out why 2 emails were opening it up online (maybe because I'm phrasing my issue wrong so I decided to post here)

My code is :

```
Set msg1 = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
msg1.Subject = "Assignments " & Format(Now, "m/dd/yyyy")
Set msg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("File Location")
msg.Display
msg1.Display
```

I want both of the Display commands to be placed in one email and not 2 seperate ones. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: You have 2 msg Display

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to create a new mail based on a template.
So at first you have to create a new mail from the template and then modify its Subject line:

```
 Set msg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("File Location")
 msg.Subject = "Assignments " & Format(Now, "m/dd/yyyy")
 msg.Display
```

Comment: I understand now based on  the code that you wrote. I thought that the variable msg could only do 1 function and not be partioned into writing both a subject and displaying the outlook template. Thank you so much!